# 'Duplicating' code so it can be used multiple times in Java

Tags: java

Is it possible to duplicate a line or multiple lines of code in order to shorten the code a bit? I'm a bit new at Java so I'm attempting to learn how to make myself efficient.

So, for a quick example, I would like to 'duplicate' this line of code to be able to be used in multiple if statements. Just by referencing say, a smaller line of code. Without having to copy paste, etc.

```
System.out.println("Long paragraph here");
```

I'm not entirely even sure if this is possible without creating a new file to be referenced. Would this be able to be done easily? Thanks for helping out a newbie. I couldn't find anything in the search because I'm not sure what the term for this would be.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(computer_programming)

Comment: Add your own method.

Comment: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_methods.htm

Comment: This is what's known as a method, procedure, function, subroutine ... depending on where you were raised.

Comment: (This was, in fact, pretty much the very first programming construct to be invented -- goes back to the days when folks coded machine language by hand.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could make a method that takes a string representing that paragraph and then call that method each time you need it:

```
void printMethod(String paragraph) {
    System.out.println(paragraph);
}
```

Or if you are always printing the same paragraph:

```
void printParagraph() {
    System.out.println("Long Paragraph");
}
```

Answer (score 4):

In order to avoid repeating code, create a method. For example:

```
public static void printParagraph() {
    System.out.println("Long paragraph here");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A good practice, if applicable is to use abstraction and inheritance to avoid code duplication. For example a behavior(method) can be placed in a parent class and then child classes can inherit the method for usage.